# Get objects of DataWindow band

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

How can i get an array of all objects in specific band, Detail or Header for example?

I success to get all objects using:

```
dw_1.Describe("datawindow.objects")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `datawindow.visualobjects` property that lists all the visible objects and for each object, you ask `object_name.band` to check if you want it.

An example that reuses the [PbniRegex](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html#pbni) (that provides the `uo_regex` object in the code below) to simplify the properties parsing :

```
public function long of_get_band_controls (string as_band_name, ref string as_controls[]);
string ls_empty[]
int i, j
as_controls[] = ls_empty[]

uo_regex lnv_regex
lnv_regex = create uo_regex
lnv_regex.initialize( "([^\t]+)", true, false)
i = lnv_regex.search( describe("Datawindow.visualobjects") )
for j = 1 to i
    if describe( lnv_regex.match( j ) + ".band" ) = as_band_name  then
        as_controls[ upperbound(as_controls[])+1 ] = lnv_regex.match( j )
    end if
next
destroy lnv_regex

return upperbound( as_controls[] )
end function
```

That code comes from a datawindow herited object, hence it gets direct access to the `describe` method.

Comment: Sebastien, AFAIK `visualobjects` is for some reason undocumented, and therefore not formally supported. [I once asked about that](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sybase.public.powerbuilder.datawindow/iZ3ZjtLQ6us/discussion) in a Sybase newsgroup, and was advised not to use it. I doubt there will ever be a problem with it, but I think whoever uses it should at least be aware of that possibility.

Comment: @eran, Oh, it's undocumented ? It must be a property that we found by chance when using the [DW debug machine](http://geni.embeddingperl.com/index.php?post/2011/06/06/My-Datawindow-DebugMachine) that lists all dw attributes through the `datawindow.attributes` property. Well, as the PB Classic virtual machine is phasing out, I suppose that it won't hurt to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any direct way to get that list, but once you have the complete list of objects, you can go over them and check each one's band:

```
ls_Obj = GetNextObjectFromList(ls_AllObjectsList)
ls_Band = dw_1.Describe(ls_Obj + ".band")
choose case ls_Band
  case "detail"
    // handle detail band objects
  case "header"
    // handle header band objects
  // etc.
end choose
```

Comment: What is the `GetNextObjectFromList()` that you use in your example ? You use it to parse the list of DW visual objects ?

Comment: @Seki, yes. Just a simple parser to obtain the next object from the list. No such built-in function, of course.